# Modifying Spring Cloud Gateway routes at runtime

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to add or delete Spring Cloud Gateway routes at runtime while the server is running.
I'm using the [Fluent Java Routes API](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#fluent-java-routes-api) to initialize gateway routes. This is working perfectly.

However, now I'd like to modify, add, and delete routes while the Spring Cloud Gateway server is running. I can see that the [RouteLocator](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-core/2.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/route/RouteLocator.html) contains my routes, but I see no methods to modify its contents.

Even though I see some ability to [create new routes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#creating-and-deleting-a-particular-route) in the actuator, I need to use add them using Java code instead of REST calls.
In my setup the [RouteDefinitionRepository](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-core/2.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/route/RouteDefinitionRepository.html) is empty, so I didn't see any way to use this in my use case.

Is it possible to modify routes at runtime using just Java code in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Comment: In current Spring cloud gateway no method to delete route define by Fluent Java Routes API. A not good method is define all routes through Actuator API and use API to operate routes

Comment: @TongChen you can do it by filtering routes before being cached as below

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Integration instead.
You can use the Java DSL to register and delete Integration Flows.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to remove routes, to hide service from gateway. Try instanciating a custom RouteLocator like bellow:

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {

    final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${route.ignore.service-ids}")
    private String[] ignoreServiceIds;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        if(ignoreServiceIds != null){
            for(String s: ignoreServiceIds){
                LOGGER.info("ServiceID ignored: {}",s);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "cachedCompositeRouteLocator")
    public RouteLocator cachedCompositeRouteLocator(List<RouteLocator> routeLocators) {

        return new CachingRouteLocator(new CustomCompositeRouteLocator(Flux.fromIterable(routeLocators), ignoreServiceIds));
    }
}
```

and then apply filter:

```
public class CustomCompositeRouteLocator implements RouteLocator {

    private final Flux<RouteLocator> delegates;
    private List<String> ignoredServiceIds;

    public CustomCompositeRouteLocator(Flux<RouteLocator> delegates, String[] ignoreServiceIds) {
        this.delegates = delegates;

        if(ignoreServiceIds != null && ignoreServiceIds.length>0)
            this.ignoredServiceIds = List.of(ignoreServiceIds);
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Route> getRoutes() {

        if(ignoredServiceIds == null || ignoredServiceIds.isEmpty())
            return this.delegates.flatMapSequential(RouteLocator::getRoutes);
        return this.delegates.flatMapSequential(RouteLocator::getRoutes).filter(p->!ignoredServiceIds.contains(p.getUri().getHost()));
    }
}
```

and in the **application.yaml**

```
...
route:
  ignore:
    service-ids: MY_IGNORED_SERVICE_ID
...
```